# Plotting Data with Discontinuous X-Axis Data in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have some data that is plotted against dates (days).

Now, if the data is "continuous" (meaning, I have a data point for every day), there is no problem -- I can just let Excel do "auto" on everything and a "line" chart works as expected, when plotting the data point (Y-Axis) against the date (X-Axis).

However, if there are gaps in the data, (and the dates) - where I have a date+data value on eratic days, the normal line plot doesn't "work" properly... So when comparing plots from one 10-day period against anothe 10-day period for example, they are not visually comparable, as  the X-Axis values are missing.

Is there a way that I can specify the X-Axis scaling to still do the plotting 'every day' and now show any data point when the data is missing... OR will I need to do some machinations with multiple columns and formulas, etc to "build" a range with the continuous days and build the chart as usual?

I simply want to use the 'standard' features of Excel and not have to do something with VBA, etc.

Edit: Thanks for the clues about Scatter plots...  Although, I'm still trying to find the 'break on gaps in data' -type setting...  An example:

[image: image of different types of charts]

Comment: take a look at scatter plots instead of line plots.  Scater plots will place data points at their proper place where a line graph gives every point equal spacing.  IE a line plot with 5 days one after the other may look right in both scatter an line.  However if one of those days were to skip due to a weekend or a holiday, the line plot would still look the same where a scatter would leave a bigger gap where the weekend or holiday was jumped over.

Comment: It is also possible to tell excel what to do when it hit a gap in the data series.  Its one of the options when setting up the data.

Comment: Right click the chart > Select Data > click Empty and Hidden Cells > for blank cells, draw line connecting points.

Answer (score 3):

In an Excel line chart with dates on the X axis you can format the X axis to plot the data as a text axis or a date axis. If you select date axis, the X axis will have **all** the dates.

Chart plotted with text axis, data points are spaced evenly

[image]

The same chart plotted with a date axis, **all** dates are on the X axis:

[image]

If you don't have data for all dates, click **Select Data** on the Chart Design ribbon, then click the button for **Hidden and Empty Cells** and select "Connect Data points with Line".

Chart with missing data points:

[image]

Chart plotted connecting empty data cells with line:

[image]